# Reduced residue systems $\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

We know that if $p$ is prime and $1\leq a,b<p$ then $\{a\cdot 1+b,a\cdot 2+b,...,a\cdot (p-1)+b\}$ is a reduced residue system $\pmod{p}$.
We also know that if $g$ is a primitive root modp then $\{ g^1,...,g^{p-1}\}$ is also a reduced residue system modp.
Are there any other (non-trivial) examples of sets who form a reduced residue system modp?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitive_Root_is_Generator_of_Reduced_Residue_System

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, I know I mentioned primitive roots.

Comment: It should be reduced residue, not a complete one.